# how to make url from action data parameter in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have

> data-post="**{"action":"http://local.test.com/ar_eb/stores/store/redirect/","data":{"___store":"en_eb","___from_store":"ar_eb","uenc":"aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsLmV5ZWJvdS5jb20vZW5fZWIvY2F0YWxvZy9wcm9kdWN0L3ZpZXcvaWQvMTIwNTAvLmh0bWw,"}}**"

how can I make it redirectUrl like below:

> http://local.eyebou.com/en_eb/stores/store/redirect/___store/ar_eb/___from_store/en_eb/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsLmV5ZWJvdS5jb20vYXJfZWIvY2F0YWxvZy9wcm9kdWN0L3ZpZXcvaWQvMTIwNTAvLmh0bWw%2C/.html">
>                               عربي

in Magento2

Comment: Why do you need like that?

Comment: I want to make ajax call to change the store so i have data-post params but i don't know how to make form below url

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try something like below.
First, get the data-post value and json decode it, so that you can make it in array format.

```
$dataPost = json_decode(Your data post variable here);
```

Now extract the required parameters from it to make the target redirect url.

```
$targetBaseUrl = $dataPost["action"]; 
$fromStore = $dataPost["___from_store"];
$toStore = $dataPost["___store"];
$urlEnc = $dataPost["uenc"]."%2C/.html";
```

Now combine the parts to make the target url.

```
$targetRedirUrl = $targetBaseUrl . '/___store/'. $fromStore . '/___from_store/' . $toStore . '/uenc/' . $urlEnc;
```

Try to print the created redirect url to make sure the parts are in correct sequence. There might be another ways, but  I think this will help you.

If it's the front-end, you can apply same idea using javascript.

Comment: Whomever negative voted, I would like to know the reason and please post your answer. That would be the professional way to negative vote.